# Can MobileIron MDM detect if an app is uninstalled from an iOS device and clear that app's Keychain data?

Tags: ios, uninstallation, keychain, mdm

Can MobileIron MDM - installed and configured for an iOS device - detect whether an app is uninstalled from that device and perform certain operations like clearing the Keychain data (keys, certificates,..) specific to that particular app?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this is not a software development question, so most likely it will be closed. So, I would recommend to reframe it.

Second, iOS MDM allows to get a list of installed apps. So, as results, if you poll device for a list of devices periodically, you MDM Server will be able to detect uninstallation of some application.

MDM protocol doesn't have a command for clearing keychain. There are several destructive commands in MDM protocol:

- Wipe (it deletes all data)
- Remove configuration profile (it deletes this config profile, as example Exchange account info)
- Uninstall app (it can uninstall only apps which were previously installed through MDM)